# DAX / Powerpivot: how to do a "IF Parent of pivot row >x"

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

Searching for a way to do the following; any help is greatly appreciated!

Setup: Excel 2013 & Powerpivot;

**Pivot in Values:**

Value #1 and #2 Sum of numeric values

Calculated field in Value #3 (% of Value #1)

Calculated field in Value #4 (Value #3 - Value#2)

Value #5 and #6 Sum of numeric values (different than #1 and #2)

Calculated field in Value #7 (% of Value #5)

Calculated field in Value #8 (Value #7 - Value#6)

**Rows in Pivot**

Row#1 Area

Row#2 District

Row#3 Cluster ID

Trying to create new calculated field that will do the following (showing via an excel formula to describe)

```
If(and(District Value#4)>0,ClusterID Value#8>0),1,2)
```

Any idea how this can be done in DAX / Powerpivot ?????

I have tried Hierarchies, but no luck.

Calculated formulas will allow me to see the pivot row name, so maybe a filter, but cant seem to get the syntax correct, assuming it is even allowed...

[image]
Stuck..

All suggestions are very much appreciated !

Comment: This question isn't off topic.  It's asking for a DAX formula. We have DAX questions all the time, hence the availability of the tag. It's no different than asking a SQL question. Power Pivot is like a local instance of SSAS tabular.

Comment: DAX and PowerPivot are on-topic for this site. One is a programming language and the other is the data source. Just because it's Excel doesn't mean it's a SuperUser type of question.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPivot has some pretty powerful features for adjusting its calculations to its context (rows).

If there is anything specific I want to do with just the row parents (= totals), function *HASONEVALUE()* is the way to go.

```
IF(HASONEVALUE(Stores[StoreName]), [Units Sold], BLANK())
```

This command will calculate expression *Units Sold* for all the rows but row parents. You might need to switch it, but generally this should be an easiest and most reliable way how to identify row parents.

I couldn't understand your question and wasn't sure about the calculations you are doing, so I apologize for not giving a more detailed response... Hope this will help.

Also, see this [brilliant article](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/03/hasonevalue-vs-isfiltered-vs-hasonefilter/) by Rob Collie.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I am trying to do the reverse, I am trying to perform an IF calc based on the parent of the row.

S0... Parent of the row in column A = 10

the row in column B =5

Look to create a calc that say IF( Parent in Column A + row in Column B =15, "true", "false")

So in this case 10+5 = 15 so it would be true.

How can I use HASONEVALUE to get to the value of that parent in Column A ??

Thanks again for the help !

Larry

Comment: How about creating a new measure, that does exactly that (sums column A and column B), and then adding a new measure, something like:
=IF(value>[NewMeasure], true, false) ?

Comment: Am I missing something simple ?  I am trying to do a calc in an IF that looks exclusively at the top of the parent and than the individual row to come to a true false conclusion. I think (again unless I am missing something), if I do the sum column A and B I will still be only evaluating the row, not the parent plus the row ??  Thoughts.  Appreciate the help (again)

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. It's hard to see and give advice without the source data. I thought that if you sum up the totals in a separate measure, you could do an IF. But I didn't realize you need to add the actual row value...

Comment: Yes. its a little hard to describe.  The screen shot above helps a little.  But basically, say you have a 6 column set of data, column A is Area, Column B is District, Column C is Cluster, column D is Number of Widgets, Column E is number of Full time Employees, and Column F is number of Part time employees. Than pivot the rows on Area, District and Cluster, than add column D Widgets, E FT Employees and F PT employees to the values.  I am trying to get the sum of District Widgets add it to the sum of District FT Employees, and add it into the sum of cluster PT employees.  Any way to do this ??

Comment: why do you have columns identical to rows? :)

Comment: As to the columns, they are not identical, the rows represent the Hierarchical, the columns represent the head counts, so the sums are the head counts by type of employee at the area/district/cluster and store levels. The calcs are about employee caps. So if the district is over, the cluster or store can not hire, if the district and cluster is in cap than if the store is under cap they can hire. So the calc I am struggling with wants to do an "IF" the district is under cap than evaluate if the cluster is under cap, if false, no one can hire.

Comment: Everything I try only looks at the row individually. If this was a static sheet and not a pivot, I would use $Column$row for all the children of the district.  That's where I am stuck, evaluating the parent (district) for all the children of the district, than if the district is >0, evaluating the row to see if they are >0, if all true, the store can hire.

Comment: oh, now I think I get it :) the screen looked a bit confusing. just to clarify -- where is the cap coming from? if the hierarchy (district/cluster/store) is coming from the same table, is it true to say that by definition the over/under cap is most important for the stores -- meaning if the cap is over for the stores, there is no way it can be under for cluster/district. Correct?

Comment: The caps are a calc from 4 different column sums from the PowerPoint table. So by using the standard powerpivot, I show the totals of the counts, than using a calculated field, do the math against the  "[Sum of ColumnName]" which shows all the totals by Area / District Etc. Now the hard part: is a new calculated formula that filters to use the calculated cap number but only at the district hierarchy.  the actual math would be an IF(and( District CAP1 <0, district CAP2<0, Cluster Cap3)<0, "Hire", Do Not Hire".  Hopefully that makes sence...:)

Comment: So in reality, even if your Cluster (store) is under cap, if your district in total is out of compliance, you cant hire.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response -- could you please share some sample data (with fake numbers...), it might help finding the answer about which I am not sure right now :)